# Would asking to identify a Manga Drawing Guide, be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

[Tineye](https://tineye.com/) reveals that this image is from before 2009 and a reddit thread somewhere said it looked like from a manga drawing book, like "Super Manga Matrix".

[image: Cute Monster Girl]

Would asking where this girl came from, be on-topic? Or no, because it's not a story?

Comment: The character would be on topic and you don't 100% know it's from a drawing book anyway so I don't see the problem.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slovakia/comments/axtktp/does_anyone_have_an_account_on_the_website/ - It looks like you're not the only one looking for a source on that picture

Comment: For the record, it's not from *Super Manga Matrix*.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be on-topic

Comment: I see community consciousness seems to indicate it's in topic but what is it's just fan made? Nowdays there are many AI which can make any such random image with keyword or many artist famous for making such art out of thin air without connection to any anime or hentai

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I assume you missed the "is from before 2009"?

Comment: @Malady artists predates 2009 and this can be used as a refrence for future questions.

Answer (score 12):

Asking us to identify the origin of a picture of a clearly non-human girl (one with dragon wings, blue skin, red eyes, horns and a tail) would be entirely on-topic.

It's pretty clear that she's intended to be a 'fantasy' character of some sort, and hence well within our scope.

Comment: Thanks! Making the Question now! - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270701/wheres-this-japanese-student-looking-winged-girl-from